# Setting Javascript variable inside for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I looked at a lot of posts around global/local variables but I think I'm missing something. 
This is what I'm trying to get to:

```
var commandList = {
    'command_a': function() {
        socket.emit({action: 'a'});
    },
    'command_b': function() {
        socket.emit({action: 'b'});
    }
};
```

Instead of defining my list of commands, I would like to define them dynamically from an ajax call.
This is my best attempt:

```
function getCommands() {
    $.ajax({
        type:'get',
        url: '/getCommands',
        data: data,       
        success: function(data) {

            JSONdata = $.parseJSON(data);
        // [{"action": "b", "command": "command_b"},{"action": "a", "command": "command_a"}]

            var commandList = [];

            jQuery.each(JSONdata, function( i, val ) {

                command = val['command'];
                action = val['action'];

                service = {
                    [command]: function() {
                        socket.emit({action: [action]});
                    }
                console.log(service[Object.keys(service)[0]]);
                }
                commandList.push(service);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The main problem is that in my loop, my `action` variable doesn't get replaced by `a` or `b` in `service`, which I assume is because `action` only gets defined when the function is called. The `console.log` returns:

```
function () {
                    socket.emit({action: [action]});
                }
```

Instead of:

```
function () {
                    socket.emit({action: 'a'});
                }
```

Comment: i think u need to add "var" before JSONdata = $.parseJSON(data)

Comment: Where is `channel` defined?

Comment: @guest271314 sorry it was a typo, fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, always declare your variables with the `var` keyword. If you don't, they are created in the global scope, polluting it. More importantly, failing to do so breaks your code, as i will explain later. I will assume from now on they are correctly declared with var.

Let's start by replacing `socket.emit({action: [action]});` with `socket.emit({action: action});`. Your code will behave correctly, i.e., when you call `service[Object.keys(service)[0]]`, the socket will emit `{action: 'a'}`. However you will not get the output you expect from the console log. The console log shows:

```
function () {
                socket.emit({action: action});
            }
```

because that is how you defined the function, you did not define it with the string literal "a". But this is no problem at all, since action will be substituted by "a" at runtime. In javascript, functions are created with a reference to the scope on which they are created, which means they can access any variable of that scope, even when they are called outside that scope. Good explanation here http://javascript.info/tutorial/closures.

So, to sum it up, your `command_a` function will hold a reference to `action` when its value is "a" and your `command_b` function will hold a reference to `action` when its value is "b", if and only if you declared `var action`!!!!

Notice that if you don't declare `action` with `var action`, it will be in the global scope, and it will hold the last value (i.e. "a") after your code executes. When either `command_a()` or `command_b()` are called, they will both emit `{action: 'a'}`, because `action` lives in the global scope.

One last thing, you originally wanted `commandList` to be an object, but the code you are using creates an array. This would give you an object as initially stated:

```
function getCommands() {
$.ajax({
    type:'get',
    url: '/getCommands',
    data: data,       
    success: function(data) {

        JSONdata = $.parseJSON(data);
    // [{"action": "b", "command": "command_b"},{"action": "a", "command": "command_a"}]

        var commandList = {};

        jQuery.each(JSONdata, function( i, val ) {
            var command = val['command'];
            var action = val['action'];

            commandList[command] = function() {
                    socket.emit({action: action});
            };
        });
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Thank you! Your answer and the link you included were incredibly helpful to understand better scopes and variables in cases like mine.

Answer (score 1):

This should be the syntax

`service = {};
service[command] = function (){
  var actionObj ={};
  actionObj.action = action;
  socket.emit(actionObj);
}`

Answer (score 1):

Try removing brackets surrounding `action` at `socket.emit({action: action});`. Also, `console.log(service[Object.keys(service)[0]]);` is outside of function body at `[command]:function(){}`, creating a syntax error; moved to after after `service` definition.

```
var commandList = [];

jQuery.each(JSONdata, function(i, val) {

  var command = val["command"];
  var action = val["action"];

  var service = {
    [command]: function() {
      socket.emit({action: action}); // removed brackets at value `action`
    }
  };
  console.log(service[Object.keys(service)[0]]); // moved outside of `service`
  commandList.push(service);
});
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/VkmPGl9lWwiPKarvrbLJ?p=preview